# How can I implement Javascript into a Windows Phone 8.0 HTML5 Application?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8

I've been developing a Windows Phone 8.0 application using secure bootstrap HTML (In Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 2.34 build 32-4) and have begun to try implementing JavaScript. However, here is where I have become stuck. I have set 'IsScriptEnabled' to true and, for testing purposes, have created very basic inline JavaScript with . Yet despite my best efforts, my scripts simply do not run. Can anybody help with the implementation?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sounds like a relative/fullpath linking problem.  If you're using the HTML5 App Template the IsScriptEnabled is default true.  Try creating a blank HTML5 app with an alert directly inside the HTML file.  You will see that it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that your javascript is working and the your "very basic inline javascript" is incorrect. The windows phone 8.0 IDE does not support `Console.log();` and you will be better off with alerts such as:
`alert("test");`